# Which names and terms in the Dune series come from Hebrew-inspired phrases?

Tags: dune, frank-herbert

Kwisatz Haderach is one example of a name that is inspired by a [Hebrew phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kefitzat_Haderech). What is a complete list of terms that are used in Dune and share this property?

Comment: There are also (even more) Latin/Roman-inspired phrases/terms, as well as Arabic ones.

Comment: The verb hadara (spelling?) in Arabic means "to come," and is the same radical used to denote a messiah, as in "coming of the messiah."

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Most of the Semitic-language-derived terms in Dune are proximately from Arabic rather than Hebrew.  Looking over a [glossary of Dune terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dune_terminology), I see these that look relevant to your question:

- **Aba** has been Islamified, but the term (and/or "abaya") apparently shows up in Tanach as the garb of Hebrew prophets.
- **Arafel** is Hebrew (ערפל).
- **Baraka** is probably Arabic-derived, but has such closely related meanings in Arabic and Hebrew as to make little difference.
- The "Bene" in **Bene Gesserit** and **Bene Tleilax** is, if pronounced with the stress on the second syllable, Hebrew for "children of" (more popularly transliterated *b'nei* or *b'nai* ).  It's remotely possible that "Bene Gesserit" is meant to allude to a distorted Hebrew for "children of the narrow path", but as others have noted, it's more likely straight from Latin.  "Tleilaxu" is not Hebrew (neither it nor Arabic have an X), but the "Bene" in "Bene Tleilax" is more likely to be from the Semitic "children of" rather than the Latin "good", the Tleilaxu being Zensufis and all.
- **Fedaykin** is probably from Arabic "fedayeen", but Hebrew has pretty much the same word, פַדַאיוּן
- **Sayyadina** I suspect of being derived from an Arabic term with Hebrew roots, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Also "qanat": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qanat

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff: Seems to be strictly Arabic?  I didn't mention "qaid" for the same reason.

Comment: Indeed, it was Arabic that primarily influenced the terminology and some of the content of Dune. Hebrew doesn't seem to come into it much.

Comment: Also, the most likely origin of the term *Bene Gesserit* is from *Latin*, not Hebrew. In fact it appears undistorted in the long-standing Latin legal phrase "quamdiu se bene gesserit". *Gesserit* may also have been chosen to evoke the word *Jesuit* (especially since Herbert pronounced it with a soft G, unlike in Latin). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bene_gesserit for more info.

Comment: Alia is Latin, exactly meaning “other”. As in “alias”.

Also, it didn’t occur to me that Bene Gesserit was anything other than Latin as well, because it fits Latin verb declension so well. Plus, it can also translate to “she carries (a burden/burdens) well” or “she manages well”

Comment: Isn’t Baraka Hebrew for “one with forearm blades?”

Comment: the word 'umma' is used in the appendix "The Ecology of Dune" - and is used in essentially the same manner as the semetic and more recognized Arabic word 'ummah' denoting a community of people

Comment: "Bene Gesserit" seems most likely derived from Hebrew, as it was also translated as "Bnot Gishrit" (literally, daughters of the bridge-like) in the Hebrew version (1976). "Fedaykin" has no Hebrew counterpart, it's completely Arabic-originated; פדאיון is not really a Hebrew word, but a nickname to Arabic terrorist groups in Israel's history, derived from the Arabic word. "Sayyadina" also doesn't sound like Hebrew, but maybe it's derived from Aramaic.

Comment: @SillybutTrue No, Baraka is in Arabic and it's Hebrew counterpart is "Bracha", which means "a blessing".

Comment: @NKCampbell "Uma" in Hebrew is "a nation", but I don't see the relation.

Comment: @EyalRoth - Which is very similar to the Arabic usage. The usage in the text is: "he was one of the umma, the brotherhood of prophets." Later, it is defined: "A term of scorn in the Imperium, meaning any 'wild' person given to fanatical prediction" - as I said, it's likely a 20,000 year bastardization of the original useage of *either* (which are loosely related imo) :)

Comment: @NKCampell I guess it could be related, but "uma / a nation" would be more appropriate to groups such as the Fremen, I believe 

Answer (score 4):

The Bene in Bene Tleilax is from Arabic (they were [Zensufis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dune_religions#Zensufism), remember) but probably changed through analogy with the Bene of Bene Gesserit, which is Latin.

Comment: Bene Gesserit translates to “she carries (a burden/burdens) well” or “she manages well”. Always thought that was especially genius, in books already full of genius.

Answer (score 4):

[Kwisatz Haderach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kefitzat_Haderech) is Hebrew, see the link.

Comment: See also http://literature.stackexchange.com/q/409/139 "Where did the term Kwisatz Haderach in Dune originate?"

Answer (score 3):

- aba means "father" in Hebrew.
- Baraka was the Hebrew Jewish Prophet, Dvorah or Deborah, husband in the original Hebrew Israel scrolls (book of Deborah)
- Bene may refer to "within" in Hebrew
- Jihad is "holy war" to certain Islam sectors or it may refer to just "war"

Answer (score 3):

Native Hebrew speaker here.

I went through the [glossary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Dune_(franchise)_terminology) / [terminology](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Dune_terminology) of the book and and tried to speculate what could be derived from Hebrew. As others mentioned here before, Hebrew and Arabic are both Semitic languages, and so many words may sound similar; however, knowing either of the languages does not by any means provide you with sufficient knowledge of understanding the other one.

**Sounds like Hebrew and probably is:**

- Arafel (ערפל) - "fog" or "mist" in Hebrew.
- [Behemoth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behemoth).
- Bene - "B'nei" (בני) in Hebrew means "sons of", like [Bene Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bene_Israel).
- Bene Gesserit - I understand this is controversial, but to me it seems to be most likely Hebrew. In the Hebrew translation of the book (from 1976), this is translated as "Bnot Gishrit" (בנות גשרית), which is just the more accurate Hebrew pronunciation (though "bnot" is "daughters of" and not "sons of", which makes sense as they are all female). "Gishrit" just means "of bridge" or "bridge like" in a feminine tense, which very much fits the role of the order.
- Cherem - [Herem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herem) in Hebrew.
- [Kadesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadesh_(biblical)).
- Leb Kamai - "Lev" (לב) in Hebrew is "a heart", "Kamai" (קמאי) could be the arcane word for "primeval".
- [Kedem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9D#:%7E:text=Noun,east%20(cardinal%20direction)%20quotations%20%E2%96%BC).
- Kwisatz Haderach - "Kfitzat" means "jump of", "Ha" means "the" and "derech" means "road/path/route/way". "Kfitzat derech" (קפיצת דרך), without "Ha'", means "breakthrough"; however, with the "Ha'" (קפיצת הדרך), this refers to an expression in Judaism which means "fast transition from place to place by miracle", and "Kfitza" is not to be taken literally, but as to mean "shortening", as if shortening the passage between places.
- Ze'eb - "Ze'ev" (זאב) in Hebrew is "a wolf".

**Arabic but sounds like Hebrew too:**

- Abu - "father" in Arabic, "Aba" (אבא) in Hebrew.
- Alam - "world" in Arabic, "Olam" (עולם) in Hebrew.
- Bahr - "body of water" in Arabic, "Be'er" (באר) in Hebrew is "a well".
- Baraka - "blessing" in Arabic, "Bracha" (ברכה) in Hebrew.
- Hajra, Harj - [Hegira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hegira) in Arabic, "Hagira" (הגירה) in Hebrew is "migration".
- Ke'leb - "Kalb" in Arabic is "dog", "Kelev" (כלב) in Hebrew.
- Well actually there's more but you get the gist.

**Sounds like Hebrew but probably isn't:**

- Aba - Again, "father" (אבא) in Hebrew. Maybe it's like the robe that fathers in a religious order wear?
- Ach - "brother" (אח) in Hebrew.
- Alia Cult - Maybe derived from [Aliyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliyah)?
- Arrakis - Sounds like [Arak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arak_(drink)). Not Hebrew (but a common drink in Israel).
- Auqaf - Sounds like 'Ukaf' (אוכף), which is "a saddle".
- Derch - "Derech" (דרך) in Hebrew is "road/path/route/way" (just like in "Kwisatz Haderach").

Answer (score 2):

Most of the phrases came from Hebrew though the shemic languages are pretty similar.
When you say about someone that he made "Kwisatz Haderach" in free translation from Hebrew it means he made a major leap forward, let’s say at school. when you say a person is a "Kwisatz Haderach" in humanity you actually mean that he is the next stage of evolution.

Answer (score 0):

Also the word "mishmish" appears once - it's Hebrew for "apricot(s)" but is quite possibly also from Arabic (the languages share a lot of words).